# Modular congruence class

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let a and b be two positive integers. Show that $x ≡ c \pmod a$ if and only if $x ≡ c, c + a, c + 2a, · · · , c + (b-1)a\pmod {ab}$.

I understand why this is true, because all of the c's are the residuals and the a divisor increases with every multiple, but I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: what's your definition of equivalence $\pmod m$?

Comment: x ≡ c (mod a) means that a|(x-c)

Answer (score 1):

$x\equiv c\ (\text{mod }a) \Longleftrightarrow x= ak+c\ (\exists k\in \mathbb{Z})$

so if $k=lb+r$ for some $l\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $r\in [0,b-1]\cap \mathbb{Z}$

then $x=l(ab)+ra+c$

hopefully that's enough.

Comment: Ok so you've shown that a|(x-c), but how do you create the equivalence class, and how do you show that ab also divides it?

Comment: ab doesn't also divide it. ab divides one of the ${ x-c, x+a-c, x+2a-c,...}$ according to the question.

Comment: OH ok, so depending on what l is l can be 0 and make x=ra+c then too right?

Comment: I don't know what you just said.